# Javascript to jquery a document.get with children

Tags: javascript, jquery

What is the equivalent of this to jquery and how can I shorten it using children (both in jquery and javascript as I'm really curious why mine didn't work)? I tried children actually but didn't get a result I wanted.

```
document.getElementById('ShowRow').getElementsByClassName('value')[0].getElementsByTagName('a')[0].innerHTML
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: `$("#ShowRow .value a").html()`.

Comment: *"I tried children actually but didn't get a result I wanted."* can you please include that attempt? we can help you modify it to work properly.

Comment: @VisioN He only gets the first element with the class `value` and then the first `a` within that.

Comment: @Paulpro Yes, I noticed that.

Comment: @KevinB When using `.html()` the jQuery will return the very first of the very first.

Comment: Exactly with VisioN's I got undefined result

Comment: @VisioN That is true, but it could also return the `html` of the first `a` in the *second* `.value` if the first `.value` had no `a` descendant.

Comment: You need to show your HTML. Personally, I suspect a typo.

Comment: No I actually managed to do it. I made a typo :P So now I have both jquery short and jquery with children. Honestly I prefer the one VisioN used than the answers below. Ironically with javascript childrens, the script is smaller but with jquery it's bigger. With javascript I use something like this document.getElementById('ShowRow').children.item(0).children.item(0).innerHTML. Isn't that correct? If  I just use children.children I can't get result. Why is this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this:

```
$('#ShowRow').find('.value:first a:first').html()
```

Comment: I'd love to but that would mean that karthikr's wasn't correct but yo had the same answer

Comment: @viper - No that's not what it means at all. The idea is to select an answer on the site, unless none of the provided answers are acceptable.

Comment: @viper go ahead and mark either one as correct. There are no hard feelings on anyone's side. It is a forum where we help each other. So It is perfectly fine.

Comment: Just for what you said I should have marked yours but I gave you a useful comment :) Next time maybe ;) Don't worry I'll keep them coming

Answer (score 3):

You can do:

```
$('#ShowRow').find('.value:first a:first').html()
```